# Get value from first element of a sorted list

Tags: jquery, list, sorting

I have sorted a list and after sorting I need to get values of the first element in that list. I've tried it this way so far, but I'm only getting an error:

```js
let albumList = "";

albumList = $(".album:visible");
albumList.sort(function (a, b) { return $(a).data("totalprice") - $(b).data("totalprice") });

console.log(albumList[0].data("totalprice"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="170.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="200.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="150.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="100.00"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `.data()` is a jquery function make `albumList[0]`  a jquery object to use it

`$(albumList[0])`.

```js
let albumList = "";
albumList = $(".album:visible");
albumList.sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data("totalprice") - $(b).data("totalprice")
});
console.log($(albumList[0]).data("totalprice"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="170.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="200.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="150.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="100.00"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple and pure JavaScript approach.
`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList object so we first need to make an array then sort the elements by their `data` attribute.

```js
const albumList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.album')).sort((a, b) => {
    return a.dataset.totalprice - b.dataset.totalprice;
})

console.log(albumList[0].dataset.totalprice)
```

```html
<div class="album" data-totalprice="170.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="200.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="150.00"></div>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="100.00"></div>
```